# Cuando el usuario ingresa los datos, los mismos aparecen como undefined y no se muestran en el mismo orden en que fueron ingresados

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, dom, undefined

En este código tengo una pequeña app para recomendar bebidas pero a medida que avanzaba me di cuenta que en algún momento los datos que introduce el usuario empezaron a ingresar desordenados y no en el orden como aparecen en los inputs y aparte de que se pinta undefined en el DOM y no entiendo por qué. Entiendo que en algún lado estoy accesando a las propiedades del objeto de manera equivocada pero no logro entender donde y sobre todo por que me aparecen los elementos desarreglados en el DOM.

```
class Receta {
    constructor(nombre, ba, cantidadba, bna, cantidadbna, fruta, deco){
        this.nombre = nombre.toUpperCase();
        this.ba = ba;
        this.cantidadba = cantidadba;
        this.bna = bna;
        this.cantidadbna = cantidadbna;
        this.fruta = fruta;
        this.deco = deco;
    }    
}
const recetas = [];

let recomendarRecetas = document.getElementById('recomendarRecetas')
let espacioReceta = document.getElementById('espacioReceta')

if("Recetas" in localStorage){
    const guardadas= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Recetas'));    
    for (const i of guardadas) {
        recetas.push(new Receta(i.nombre, i.ba, i.cantidadba, i.bna, i.cantidadbna, i.fruta, i.deco));        
    }   
    mostrarReceta(recetas);
}

recomendarRecetas.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let ingredientes = recomendarRecetas.children;
    recetas.push(new Receta(ingredientes[0].value, ingredientes[1].value, ingredientes[2].value, ingredientes[3].value, ingredientes[4].value, ingredientes[5].value, ingredientes[6].value));
    mostrarReceta(recetas);
    e.target.reset();
    localStorage.setItem('Recetas',JSON.stringify(recetas));
}

function mostrarReceta(recomendaciones) {
    espacioReceta.innerHTML="";
    for (const bebida of recomendaciones) {
        let div= document.createElement("div"); 
        div.innerHTML= `<h2>Receta: ${bebida.nombre}</h2> 
                        <h5>${bebida.ba}, ${bebida.cantidadba} ml. <br>
                            ${bebida.bna}, ${bebida.cantidadbna} ml. <br>
                            ${bebida.fruta} <br>
                            ${bebida.deco} </h5>`;       
        espacioReceta.append(div);
    }
}
console.log(recetas);

let filtroRecetas = document.getElementById('filtroRecetas');

filtroRecetas.addEventListener('input',function () {    
    const filtrados= recetas.filter(bebida => bebida.nombre.includes(this.value.toUpperCase()));
    if(filtrados.length> 0){
        mostrarReceta(filtrados);  

    }else{
        espacioReceta.innerHTML="No se encontraron contactos con ese nombre";
    } 
})




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Aplicacion que recomienda cocktails</p>
        <form id="recomendarRecetas">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del Cocktail"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Bebida alcoholica">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Cantidad en ml"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Bebida no alcoholica">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Cantidad en ml"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Fruta"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Garnish/Deco"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Recomendar">
        </form><hr>
        <h5>Filtro por nombre</h5>
        <input id="filtroRecetas" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa la bebida a buscar">
        <hr>  
        <div id="espacioReceta">
        </div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```